# Draw another screen based on if/else result React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my code

```
renderContent = (order, _, isActive) => {
     return (
          <View style={[styles.child, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}>
             if ((order.id)==1) {
                   <View>
                       <Text>Hello World</Text>
                   </View>
             }
             return(
                    <View>
                       <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                   </View>
                    )
             )
}
```

Basic idea is, if id equals to 1 show me Hello World, otherwise show me Goodbye. This is my code. But it is not working.

Comment: Do you need both return statements?  Also you are not closing the tag on your outer `View`?

Comment: Return should be based on condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
renderContent = (order, _, isActive) => {
 return (
  <View style={[styles.child, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}>
    {order.id == 1
      ?
       <View>
         <Text>Hello World</Text>
       </View>
      :
       <View>
         <Text>Goodbye</Text>
       </View>
    }
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: Please add ) before last bracket